# How to save pdf form as draft

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-form, fdf

I need to save pdf forms as a draft or in editable form, so that user can fill the form multiple times then finally save it.
As per our current implementation after save the form data is saved in pdf form, which is read only, so user can not use the saved form data next time they want to edit.

Also there will be multiple pdf form files with different fields, labels etc i.e. form will be dynamic in nature as per the pdf form, which needed to filled and saved by the same method.

So, i am looking to save the form in fdf format from which i think i can reopen the form in the last save state(not sure) otherwise i need to have some meta data for forms i think which is not preferred approach as form are created by different tool and for each change to the form the meta data needed to be updated.

Any help, suggestion or example for above approach or new approach will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What users can do or cannot do, depends largely on their PDF viewer and its version. Current versions of Adobe Reader, e.g., should allow multiple edits for all PDFs...

Comment: Yes, this is supported and it needed to be done programaticaly. What i meant by multiple edit is that once user fill form it's saved, then user comes back after some later time he should be able to edit it again from where he left. Just like we modify any file or in case of email drafts.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. You say *per your current implementation the form is saved on first save in pdf format, which is read only so user can only save it once.* Why don't you use pdfs with editable forms?

Comment: Yes, the forms are editable so users are able save it after edit/fill for the first time. It's just like any html form, if it was disabled or read only, user can not edit in first time also.

Comment: Then change the form not to be read only. I still don't understand why you create those PDF forms read only to begin with...

Comment: We dont make the form read only, it's the result which is a pdf file and hence it's not editable just like any pdf file, it can only be read. Here form is created by fdf data file and pdf file and on save result is a pdf file.

Comment: *just like any pdf file, it can only be read* - that is wrong. Pdf files with AcroForm forms can have their field values changed and can then be saved with those changed values if the used pdf viewer supports this (e.g. current Adobe Reader versions do), cf. my initial comment. And Pdf files without AcroForm forms cannot be combined with fdf files.

Comment: Ok, i was not aware of it. Yes, we are able to save these field but it's for the first time only. If you can tell how to retrieve the saved values for the second time edit, it will solve my problem i am thinking :)

Comment: Please share files which illustrate the issue. In particular revisions of the same file which you can retrieve the values from at first but not later. And your current code retrieving the values.